# Pandas: create rows to fill numeric gaps

Tags: pandas

From a DataFrame like this one:

```
ref             from    to
abcd            1       2
efgh            2       4
ijkl            1       3
mnop            3       4
qrst            4       4
uvwx            4       6
```

The idea would be to "fill gaps" between columns `from` and `to` so as to obtain:

```
ref             value
abcd            1
abcd            2
efgh            2
efgh            3
efgh            4
ijkl            1
ijkl            2
ijkl            3
mnop            3
mnop            4
qrst            4
uvwx            4
uvwx            5
uvwx            6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `numpy` approach

```
r = df['ref'].values
f = df['from'].values
t = df['to'].values
pd.DataFrame(dict(
        ref=r.repeat(t - f + 1),
        value=np.concatenate([np.arange(f, t + 1) for f, t in zip(f, t)])
    ))

     ref  value
0   abcd      1
1   abcd      2
2   efgh      2
3   efgh      3
4   efgh      4
5   ijkl      1
6   ijkl      2
7   ijkl      3
8   mnop      3
9   mnop      4
10  qrst      4
11  uvwx      4
12  uvwx      5
13  uvwx      6
```

---

**Timing**

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby ref first, create a Series to fill the gaps and then transform it to a Dataframe and rename the column in the end.

```
df.groupby('ref').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(range(x['from'],x['to']+1)))\
                 .reset_index(level=1,drop=True)\
                 .reset_index()\
                 .rename(columns={0:'value'})
Out[22]: 
     ref  value
0   abcd      1
1   abcd      2
2   efgh      2
3   efgh      3
4   efgh      4
5   ijkl      1
6   ijkl      2
7   ijkl      3
8   mnop      3
9   mnop      4
10  qrst      4
11  uvwx      4
12  uvwx      5
13  uvwx      6
```