# Slow pandas DataFrame MultiIndex reindex

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame of the form:

```
                       id                start_time  sequence_no    value
0                      71 2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00       114428        3
1                      71 2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00       114429        3
2                      71 2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00       114431       79
3                      71 2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00       216009      100
4                      71 2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00       216011      150
5                      71 2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00       216013      180
6                      92 2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00       114430       19
7                      92 2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00       114433       79
8                      92 2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00       114434      100
```

What I'm trying to do is fill in the missing `sequence_no` **per** `id`/`start_time` combo.  For example, the `id`/`start_time` pairing of `71` and `2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00`, is missing sequence_no 114430.  For each added missing sequence_no, I also need average/interpolate the missing `value` column value.  So, the final processing of the above data would end up looking like:

```
                       id                start_time  sequence_no    value
0                      71 2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00       114428        3
1                      71 2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00       114429        3
2                      71 2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00       114430       41  **
3                      71 2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00       114431       79
4                      71 2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00       216009      100  
5                      71 2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00       216010      125  **
6                      71 2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00       216011      150
7                      71 2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00       216012      165  **
8                      71 2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00       216013      180
9                      92 2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00       114430       19
10                     92 2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00       114431       39  **
11                     92 2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00       114432       59  **
12                     92 2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00       114433       79
13                     92 2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00       114434      100
```

(`**` added to the right of newly inserted rows for easier readability)

My original solution for doing this relied heavily on Python loops over a large table of data, so it seemed like the ideal place for numpy and pandas to shine. Leaning on SO answers like [Pandas: create rows to fill numeric gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44578607/3362468), I came up with:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame([
    (71, '2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00', 114428, 3),
    (71, '2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00', 114429, 3),
    (71, '2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00', 114431, 79),
    (71, '2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00', 216009, 100),
    (71, '2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00', 216011, 150),
    (71, '2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00', 216013, 180),
    (92, '2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00', 114430, 19),
    (92, '2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00', 114433, 79),
    (92, '2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00', 114434, 100),   
], columns=['id', 'start_time', 'sequence_no', 'value'])

# create a new DataFrame with the min/max `sequence_no` values for each `id`/`start_time` pairing
by_start = df.groupby(['start_time', 'id'])
ranges = by_start.agg(
    sequence_min=('sequence_no', np.min), sequence_max=('sequence_no', np.max)
)
reset = ranges.reset_index()

mins = reset['sequence_min']
maxes = reset['sequence_max']

# Use those min/max values to generate a sequence with ALL values in that range
expanded = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    start_time=reset['start_time'].repeat(maxes - mins + 1),
    id=reset['id'].repeat(maxes - mins + 1),
    sequence_no=np.concatenate([np.arange(mins, maxes + 1) for mins, maxes in zip(mins, maxes)])
))

# Use the above generated DataFrame as an index to generate the missing rows, then interpolate
expanded_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(expanded)
df.set_index(
    ['start_time', 'id', 'sequence_no']
).reindex(expanded_index).interpolate()
```

The output is correct, but it runs at almost exactly the same speed as my lots-of-python-loops solution.  I'm sure there are places I could cut out a few steps, but the slowest part in my testing appears to be the `reindex`.  Given that the real world data consists of almost a million rows (operated on frequently), are there any obvious ways to gain some performance advantage over what I've already written?  Any ways I can speed up this transformation?

## Update 9/12/2019

Combining the merge solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59279322/3362468) with the original construction of the expanded dataframe yields that fastest results so far, when tested on a sufficiently large dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame([
    (71, '2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00', 114428, 3),
    (71, '2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00', 114429, 3),
    (71, '2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00', 114431, 79),
    (71, '2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00', 216009, 100),
    (71, '2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00', 216011, 150),
    (71, '2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00', 216013, 180),
    (92, '2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00', 114430, 19),
    (92, '2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00', 114433, 79),
    (92, '2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00', 114434, 100),   
], columns=['id', 'start_time', 'sequence_no', 'value'])

# create a ranges df with groupby and agg
ranges = df.groupby(['start_time', 'id'])['sequence_no'].agg([
    ('sequence_min', np.min), ('sequence_max', np.max)
])
reset = ranges.reset_index()

mins = reset['sequence_min']
maxes = reset['sequence_max']

# Use those min/max values to generate a sequence with ALL values in that range
expanded = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    start_time=reset['start_time'].repeat(maxes - mins + 1),
    id=reset['id'].repeat(maxes - mins + 1),
    sequence_no=np.concatenate([np.arange(mins, maxes + 1) for mins, maxes in zip(mins, maxes)])
))

# merge expanded and df
merge = expanded.merge(df, on=['start_time', 'id', 'sequence_no'], how='left')
# interpolate and assign values 
merge['value'] = merge['value'].interpolate()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using `merge` instead of `reindex` may speed things up. Also, using map instead of the list comprehension may as well.

```
# Generate dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame([
    (71, '2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00', 114428, 3),
    (71, '2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00', 114429, 3),
    (71, '2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00', 114431, 79),
    (71, '2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00', 216009, 100),
    (71, '2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00', 216011, 150),
    (71, '2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00', 216013, 180),
    (92, '2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00', 114430, 19),
    (92, '2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00', 114433, 79),
    (92, '2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00', 114434, 100),   
], columns=['id', 'start_time', 'sequence_no', 'value'])

# create a ranges df with groupby and agg
ranges = df.groupby(['start_time', 'id'])['sequence_no'].agg([('sequence_min', np.min), ('sequence_max', np.max)])
# map with range to create the sequence number rnage
ranges['sequence_no'] = list(map(lambda x,y: range(x,y), ranges.pop('sequence_min'), ranges.pop('sequence_max')+1))
# explode you DataFrame
new_df = ranges.explode('sequence_no')
# merge new_df and df
merge = new_df.reset_index().merge(df, on=['start_time', 'id', 'sequence_no'], how='left')
# interpolate and assign values 
merge['value'] = merge['value'].interpolate()

                   start_time  id sequence_no  value
0   2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00  71      114428    3.0
1   2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00  71      114429    3.0
2   2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00  71      114430   41.0
3   2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00  71      114431   79.0
4   2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00  71      216009  100.0
5   2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00  71      216010  125.0
6   2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00  71      216011  150.0
7   2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00  71      216012  165.0
8   2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00  71      216013  180.0
9   2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00  92      114430   19.0
10  2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00  92      114431   39.0
11  2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00  92      114432   59.0
12  2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00  92      114433   79.0
13  2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00  92      114434  100.0
```

Comment: This was an interesting case of "one step forward, one step back".  You were correct that the `merge` is significantly faster than the `reindex`, but it turns out that the `explode` is very slow on larger data sets.  When combining your merge with the original construction of the expanded dataset, we get the fastest implementation so far (see the 9/12/2019 update to the question)

Comment: @MBrizzle Also, I should note that adding the param `copy=False` to the merge should speed things up a little as well as you will avoid any unnecessary copying of the data. `merge = expanded.merge(df, on=['start_time', 'id', 'sequence_no'], how='left', copy=False)`

Answer (score 3):

A shorter version of the `merge` solution:

```
df.groupby(['start_time', 'id'])['sequence_no']\
.apply(lambda x: np.arange(x.min(), x.max() + 1))\
.explode().reset_index()\
.merge(df, on=['start_time', 'id', 'sequence_no'], how='left')\
.interpolate()
```

Output:

```
                   start_time  id sequence_no  value
0   2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00  71      114428    3.0
1   2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00  71      114429    3.0
2   2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00  71      114430   41.0
3   2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00  71      114431   79.0
4   2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00  71      216009  100.0
5   2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00  71      216010  125.0
6   2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00  71      216011  150.0
7   2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00  71      216012  165.0
8   2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00  71      216013  180.0
9   2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00  92      114430   19.0
10  2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00  92      114431   39.0
11  2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00  92      114432   59.0
12  2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00  92      114433   79.0
13  2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00  92      114434  100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `reindex` without using `explode`:

```
result = (df.groupby(["id","start_time"])
          .apply(lambda d: d.set_index("sequence_no")
          .reindex(range(min(d["sequence_no"]),max(d["sequence_no"])+1)))
          .drop(["id","start_time"],axis=1).reset_index()
          .interpolate())

print (result)

#
    id                 start_time  sequence_no  value
0   71  2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00       114428    3.0
1   71  2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00       114429    3.0
2   71  2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00       114430   41.0
3   71  2018-10-17 20:12:43+00:00       114431   79.0
4   71  2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00       216009  100.0
5   71  2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00       216010  125.0
6   71  2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00       216011  150.0
7   71  2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00       216012  165.0
8   71  2019-11-06 00:51:14+00:00       216013  180.0
9   92  2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00       114430   19.0
10  92  2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00       114431   39.0
11  92  2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00       114432   59.0
12  92  2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00       114433   79.0
13  92  2019-12-01 00:51:14+00:00       114434  100.0
```